# Where does the cacheFactory stores data? How can we see the cached data?

Tags: angularjs, browser-cache, cachefactory

I was trying to look into the browsers resources through the developer option but could not find where the data was being cached. 
where(physical location) are the cache objects being created?
please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cache objects are stored in a hash in the `$get` function of the `$cacheFactoryProvider`.

[Here in the source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/cacheFactory.js#L87).